# CSS header doesn't come bigger when dynamic table comes bigger

Tags: css, xhtml

I want to set a header in a XHTML page, as wide as the page so I write width:100%, but I have a dynamic table so when that table makes bigger the header doesn't come bigger. What could I do to solve it?

```
#header{
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:2.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(168, 164, 164, 1); 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without html code or jsfiddle, but sounds like you should just put header outside the table, so it will remain 100% wide regardless table size